# LINQ orderBy with possible null values

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have following code:

```
var ordered = allrows.OrderByDescending(n => int.Parse(n[SelectedScore].ToString()))
            .ThenByDescending(o => int.Parse(o[FirstSelected].ToString()))
            .ThenByDescending(o => int.Parse(o[SecondSelected8].ToString()))
```

However SelectedScore, FirstSelected, SecondSelected may be empty.
I would like the order by to skip on empty ones.

So for example if FirstSelected is empty elements would be ordered first by SelectedScore then by SecondSelected.

Don't know how to do that in an elegant way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When `FirstSelected` is empty, should the resulting set (that are sorted by `SecondSelected`) appear before or after items that did have a `FirstSelected`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly. When it is empty then resulting list should be ordered only by SelectedScore and then by SecondSelected.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedScore`, `FirstSelected`, and `SecondSelected` are all variables that do not depend on the the value of the row, so you can just make the order-by call depending on whether each value is set.

In order to have a common starting point (so you don’t have to figure out which is the first set variable, to call `OrderByDescending` instead of `ThenByDescending`), you can sort by a constant value first:

```
var ordered = allrows.OrderBy(x => 0);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedScore))
    ordered = ordered.ThenByDescending(o => int.Parse(o[SelectedScore].ToString()));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstSelected))
    ordered = ordered.ThenByDescending(o => int.Parse(o[FirstSelected].ToString()));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SecondSelected))
    ordered = ordered.ThenByDescending(o => int.Parse(o[SecondSelected].ToString()));
```